# R Sys.sleep with print not working in while loops

Tags: r, timer, while-loop, sleep

I've discovered a (possibly known) problem.  When you try to use Sys.sleep inside of a while loop, it doesn't work.  Specifically, it either waits for all of the combined sleeps then prints all at once or it runs in short spurts.

Example code:

```
i1 <- 0
while (i1 < 3) {
i1 <- i1 + 1
print(1)
Sys.sleep(1)
print(2)
Sys.sleep(1)
print(3)
Sys.sleep(1)
print("GO!")
}
```

Any ideas, work arounds, or solutions?  (Other than not using a loop...)

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Post you session info? Also, can you be more descriptive of "runs in short spurts"?

Comment: By "short spurts" I mean it will run 3 or 4 lines of code - then wait 3 or 4 seconds, then run the next 3 or 4, etc.  As opposed to printing 1 line, waiting 1 second, printing the next line, etc.

Comment: I suspect your stdout is being buffered and only printed later. To test that theory, you could do `op <- options(digits.secs = 6)` then `print(Sys.time())` instead of `print(1)`, `print(2)`, etc. Maybe everything will be printed at the same time at the end, but the timestamps will be one second apart.

Comment: You might need to flush the console on some GUIs/OSes. See `?flush.console`.

Comment: @flodel You are correct, the timestamps are 1 second apart - even though the actual display is not.  Gavin Simpson I tried flush.console() and it didn't change anything.  Also restarted R just in case - no change.

Comment: I tried it with the loop set to 1 iteration and had the same result.  I thought perhaps running through multiple iterations was causing the display delay, but it's just the fact that it's in the while loop at all.  Just to be sure I also tested the exact same code, just without the loop, and it displayed as it should, with a 1 second delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On R's Windows and OS X GUIs, you'll need to use `flush.console()` to avoid exactly the behavior that you describe:

```
i1 <- 0
while (i1 < 3) {
    i1 <- i1 + 1
    print(1); flush.console()
    Sys.sleep(1)
    print(2); flush.console()
    Sys.sleep(1)
    print(3); flush.console()
    Sys.sleep(1)
    print("GO!"); flush.console()
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works perfectly.

Also thank you to Gavin who suggested this route initially - I just didn't implement it correctly.

Comment: I tried to use the looping to check the files until completion of whole looping but connection sounds not stable. http://i.imgur.com/VCIMIvA.jpg